# What is the best practice for reading items from OPC DA v1 server

Tags: python, node.js, opc, opc-da

I have a need to connect to an older OPC DA server which is v1 I believe, there are credentials setup to allow access to the server to read groups/items. However, the issue I am facing is that after trying a number of OPC DA clients, none seem to ask for any credentials upon connection or prior to connection being made.

I have tried the following applications

- Matrikon OPC
- Prosys OPC Client
- OPC DA Explorer

My main question here is, is this something that will need to be custom developed to connect and read the tags or are there other applications/clients out there we can use to aid this process?

I am open to a number of solutions, if anyone had/has similar issues I would love to hear what had to be done to overcome the problem. Unfortunately we are unable to upgrade to the newer OPC UA standard in this instance.

I have tried some applications in Python, Node.js and Node-Red but to no avail.

Comment: Which OPC server is that? Is download (trial version) available? Is documentation available? How do you know that credentials are needed from the client? Do you have an OPC client that works with that server?

Answer (score 0):

There is an extension to OPC DA called the OPC Security 1.0 specification. I have never seen it implemented though. [OPC Security 1.0 Spec](http://advosol.com/OpcSpecs/OPC%20Security%201.00%20Specification.pdf)

In Matrikon OPC Explorer v5, when you click on an OPC server, I believe if it implements the OPC Security interface, you should be able to select the OPC server and then configure the security options.

Does your OPC client connect to the server at all? To you get back any error messages attempting to create groups or add items?

Comment: Hi, yeah the client does connect but doesn't show the items/groups I require, hence my thinking around the authentication problem. I will look into this, thank you.

Comment: @AidanDonnelly Typically an OPC client has to build its own group and then add items itself. If the OPC server has implement the Browse interface you should be able to browse the address space for the tags you need. If Browse isn't implemented, you can still add items, but you need to know the ItemId string. There is something known as Public Groups where there are prebuilt groups of items, but it is rarely implemented by OPC servers.